# How to get the selected text of dynamic dropdown in jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am able to get the selected value of a dynamic dropdown using the below code

```
    $("span[id*="+ orgId +"]")[0].innerHTML=$("'input[id$=" + comanyDropDown+ "]:'selected").val();
```

I want the retriev the selcted text for which i used

$("span[id*="+ orgId +"]")[0].innerHTML=$("'input[id$=" + comanyDropDown+ "]:'selected").text();

But it will retrieve all the items of the dropdown.

I tried with

```
$("span[id*="+ orgId +"]")[0].innerHTML=$("'input[id$=" + comanyDropDown+ "]:option:'selected").text();
```

How to get the selected text of dynamic dropdown.

Comment: can u show the jQuery dropdown code

Comment: are u using jQuery combobox

Comment: No.. I am using codebehind Dropdownlist.

Comment: i did not understand what you are saying

Comment: I am having one user control which contains a dropdownlist. Based on the value selected in other page I am adding the usercontrol to the page that many times. the ids are generated dyanmically.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong. There is no `:option` selector, also you trying to filter an input element which is an option, surely your selector doesn't find such element. Try the following:

```
$("span[id*="+ orgId +"]")
      .html( $("option[id$=" + comanyTextBox + "]:selected").text() );
```

Comment: Even It will get entire text in the dropdown.